# Requiring deep understanding of robot_state_publisher and TF

Tags: turtlebot, robot-state-publisher, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I have turtlebot2, groovy, turtlebot arm. In reading the tutorial Using urdf with [robot_state_publisher](http://wiki.ros.org/urdf/Tutorials/Using%20urdf%20with%20robot_state_publisher), I'm confused in its launch file.

**Why there are two "state_publishers" ?**

one is "`robot_state_publisher`", and the other is "`state_publisher`")

By saying "***need a method for specifying what state the robot is in***" the tutorial points out the function of "`state_publisher`",

But in checking [robot_state_publisher](http://wiki.ros.org/robot_state_publisher) package we can see the function of `robot_state_publisher` is "**allows you to publish the state of a robot to tf**", which seems similar to the function of "`state_publisher`".

My goal is to broadcaster TF info, so my turtlebot arm can do grasping based on it(which have tf listening function). I have a URDF of turtlebot with arm.

Thanks for your help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/156441/requiring-deep-understanding-of-robot_state_publisher-and-tf/) by [Yantian_Zha](https://answers.ros.org/users/13706/yantian_zha/) on ROS Answers with karma: 74 on 2014-04-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The naming appears to be a bit confusing indeed. There are different representations of a robot´s state. The `state_publisher` in the tutorial publishes the [JointState](http://docs.ros.org/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/JointState.html) of the robot, while the `robot_state_publisher` publishes full 6DOF [tf](http://wiki.ros.org/tf) data for all links of the robot, essentially fusing the static information about the robot from the URDF model and the dynamically changing JointState information.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2014-08-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2